# Start rust program in cgroupv2

Tags: linux, rust, ebpf, cgroups

I wrote a BPF sockops program and attach it to a cgroupv2. This applies the BPF program to all sockets from programs in that cgroupv2. How do I go about running a Rust program in this cgroupv2?

The Rust program is creating a socket to which I want the sockops program to be applied. Unfortunately I can´t find a way to directly attach the BPF program to the socket because no rust library seems to support the required syscalls to load and attach sockops programs directly to sockets. That´s why I want to use control groups instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write the process pid into the cgroup's [cgroup.procs](https://man.archlinux.org/man/cgroups.7.en#Creating_cgroups_and_moving_processes) file. This should be done fairly early in the process to make sure resources are attributed to the right group. Alternatively you can wrap the command in [cgexec](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cgexec)